# Regarding system encoding for hindi words

Tags: xml, encoding, character-encoding, google-docs

I am facing issue of encoding. I did type some hindi words in GMail, then I copied those words to google doc. Now here when I access that document by different user accounts on different systems, that word looks different (ref in following image #1 #2). Same word when I put in xml with UTF-8 encoding, I am getting same response as Google doc.

My xml is as following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<Details>
<Hindi>">प्रश्न - विद्यार्थी प्रतिक्रिया सही है या गलत ?</Hindi> 
</Details>
```

**What I want ?** 
The result is showing as following #1 and #2 on different system

[image]

I want that
1. The word I am adding in the xml or doc, it should look same at any system.
2. I want Result as #3 that is result of two different system

Comment: Might be more of a *font issue* than an encoding issue. What do these characters look like when you *type* them into whatever program you're viewing them with?

Comment: I am typing here word in hindi (using google default converter in hindi). Font does not affect the word I typed, but when I access that google doc from other's gmail account, its showing above difference. **Remember not using any hindi font**

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's a font issue, not an encoding issue. The client where it's displaying differently simply chooses another font to display the text for some reason or another.

Samples of the same text in different fonts:

[image: fonts]

Comment: It was the issue of  different bit of Operating system. One machine has 64bit o/s and other has 32 bit O/S

Thanks for help ...